# SharePoint 2013 workflow manager message queue count is not showing any value

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

We are running SharePoint 2013 with workflow manager components and workflows are working fine without any issues.

whenever we notice the workflow message queue like the screen shot below, it is not showing any value. Where can I track the workflow message queue to troubleshoot the pending workflows .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Message Queuing makes it easy to create a workflow that updates each system. A typical design pattern is to implement an agent to interact with each system. Using a workflow-agent architecture also minimizes the impact of changes in one system on the other systems. With Message Queuing, the loose coupling between systems makes upgrading individual systems simpler.

If you want to troubleshoot pending workflows, it might not provide the error messages.

You can add “Log history” action under behind each action to check which action the workflow stuck in.